# Parent div container hiding dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Its pretty hard to recreate this in jsfiddle so I'm going to go ahead and paste a screenshot, HTML and CSS:

[image]

I'm having problem displaying the dropdown in the image above.

HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="row-fluid profile-gallery-image-container">
    <div class="span12">

        <a href="#"><img src="#"/></a>

        <div class="image-options">

            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-cog icon-white"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="delete-image">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


.profile-gallery-image-container {
max-width: 130px;
max-height: 110px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
border: 2px solid rgba(140,140,140,1);
z-index: 0;
}

.image-options {
float: right;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
position: absolute;
padding-top: 2px;
border-left: 2px solid rgba(255,128,64,1);
border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255,128,64,1);
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The image is so small that it's hard to understand what you want...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This could be to do with z-index levels or could be overflow settings.

Setting the parent container to have "overflow:visible;" would be a start - but then I'd look at position: relative on the menu CSS - that often helps matters.

But ultimately without seeing a working demo I can't figure it out.

Comment: for me `overflow:visible` work by putting on right  parent  container